# SAPI - How to stop all asynchronous speech tasks?

Tags: c++, windows, text-to-speech, speech, sapi

I'm using the Microsoft's Speech Application Programming Interface (SAPI) to enable speech in my app. However, when I try to stop asynchronous speech tasks, they stop, but after a second.

In .NET framework, I tried to stop all asynchronous speech tasks, and they stop immediately when I call the SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll. However, when I try to cancel speech in [SAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723627(v=vs.85)) (C++), speech stopped but after a second (or more). I call [ISpVoice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/jj127823(v=msdn.10))::[Speak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/jj149384(v=msdn.10)) with the SVSFlagsAsync, and of course the SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak from the [SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms720892(v=vs.85)) enumeration. I tried to call ISpVoice::Pause, then trying to speak again, but it still speaks after a second. I tried using ISpVoice::Skip also, but it didn't work. I tried ISpVoice::SetPriority to Alert, but it didn't stop the speech. I wonder if there is some [W3C SSML](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/) tag to stop speech that I will send to ISpVoice::Speak as Speech Synthesis Markup language (SSML)? Or if there is some way to stop asynchronous speech tasks immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could construct two ISpAudio interfaces, then switching between them whenever you need to stop speech.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?